# Not able to get response from API

Tags: android, web-services, retrofit2

I am not able to get any response from the API. I am using retrofit library for networking. Here is my code

```
LoginApi loginApi = APIClient.getApiClient().create(LoginApi.class);
    Call<Login> call = loginApi.loginApiCall("jkchoudhary121@gmail.com", "123456");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Login>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Login> call, @NonNull Response<Login> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()){
                Log.i("Response", response.toString());
            }
            else {
                Log.i("Error", "Wrong");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Login> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.i("Error", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

I have tried defining retrofit instance in two ways but still I am not getting the response.

Here is my Webservice.

```
public class APIClient {


private static final String base_url = "https://myUrl/api/v1/users/";

private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
// private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();

private static OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(7, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .readTimeout(7, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .writeTimeout(7, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .build();

//
public static Retrofit getApiClient() {
    if (retrofit == null) {
        //scalar is for text and gson for json obect and arrays
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(base_url)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

}

The call is going into onReponse but it is not returning anything. Here is my Login APi interface.

```
public interface LoginApi {

//login
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("login")
Call<Login> loginApiCall(@Field("email") String email,
                         @Field("password") String password);

//signup
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("register")
Call<JSONObject> signupApiCall(@Field("email") String email,
                             @Field("password") String password);
```

}

And here is my Pojo class.

```
public class Login {


@SerializedName("error")
private boolean error;

@SerializedName("message")
private String message;

public Login(boolean error, String message) {
    this.error = error;
    this.message = message;
}

public boolean getError() {
    return error;
}

public void setError(boolean error) {
    this.error = error;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
```

}

My json response looks like this

```
"error": "False",
    "message": "Logged in successfully",
```

Comment: What are you experiencing that tells you you're not getting any response? What are the errors?

Comment: the callback function is not going into if(response.isSuccessful). rather then it is giving "Wrong" in Logcat which I have defined into else

Comment: Does `response.errorBody()` give any clues as to what is wrong?

Comment: yes, the response.errorBody() says I/Error: okhttp3.ResponseBody$1@58e95f1

Comment: Sorry I meant to say if you read it like: `response.errorBody().string()`

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine.Try increasing timeout values.
change your code:

```
private static OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .readTimeout(100, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .writeTimeout(100, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .build();``
```

`